# NetworkStream.Flush() in C# Socket programming

Tags: c#, sockets

I am developing a windows application (server-client communication) in which server continuously sending the string message to the client and client reading that message through network-stream. After reading the message from the network-stream client flush the network-stream but old message still remain in network-stream.
I think this is happening due to the continuous writing the message in network-stream in server-side.

CODE
Client :

```
clientSocket.Connect("192.XXX.X.XX", 8888);
label1.Text = "Client Socket Program - Server Connected ...";
NetworkStream serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
string returndata = "";
while ((true))
{
    byte[] inStream = new byte[10025];
    serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
    returndata = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream);
    serverStream.Flush();
}
```

Server Side :

```
TcpListener serverSocket = new TcpListener(8888);
TcpClient clientSocket = default(TcpClient);
NetworkStream networkStream = null;
serverSocket.Start();
clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();
networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
Byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(task);
networkStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length);
networkStream.Flush();
```

Please tell me how can i solve this problem?

Comment: AFAIR you can't flush TCP on windows. You can only disable nagle's algo, but that's only useful to reduce latency in some scenarios, it doesn't affect correctness. Another issue is that your client-side `Flush` is nonsensical. `Flush` means "write cached data to disk(or some other lower level)". It makes no sense at all when you're only *reading*, not *writing*.

Comment: Your problem with that you expect that `Write`s and `Read`s operate on "messages". TCP is just a long stream of bytes. It may combine multiple `Write`s into a single `Read`, or split one `Write` into multiple reads. If you want to split the stream into messages, you need to introduce separators yourself. See [Data loss TCP IP C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528234/data-loss-tcp-ip-c-sharp/5528284#5528284) for a related question.

Comment: @CodesInChaos : I am new to socket programming, i just want to clear the network stream so that from client i can read latest message sent by server.

Comment: With the `serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);` size parameter is a request maximum size. The Read returns how many bytes actually are read. But you'll never know if the string is completely (until you know how many bytes you should receive) (I'm currently working on a article on my blog, but i'm not finished yet.)

Answer (score 1):

Like Jaroen already mentioned, one workaround could be that on the clientside you send in `sendbyte[0] = task.length;` so that on the serverside you know what to expect. You can then read out only the bytes from the last message, and no need to care what else is afterwards in the stream. Might also help to clear your "instream" byte-array: `Array.Clear(instream, startIndex, endIndex);`